# Wifi keeps disconnecting on ubuntu 22.04, and limited range

Tags: networking, drivers

## OS Info

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Kernel 6.2.0-34-generic

## Problem Summary

- Wifi range reduced, unable to connect at locations I used to.
- When close to router, can connect but wifi is slow and gets disconnected frequently.
- When connected to bluetooth tethering, wifi is *very* slow.

## What I've Tried

- Reset Router
- Set power saving mode in /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-power-save-smth from 3 to 2
- Delete 'docker0' (dockers ethernet interface)
- Some other things i didnt fully understand (or remember)

## Other Info

- iwconfig output:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=3 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          
docker0   no wireless extensions.

enxec2e98848f8a  no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: This same computer running a different OS worked fine?